# Android superuser

Tags: android, system, superuser

I've built a `system app` running on a `rooted/customized` version of `AOSP Android`.

It could happen that I need to download new version of my app from my personal website and replace it on Android system with the new one.

This must be done **automatically by the app itself** and not manually with adb command.

**WHAT I TRIED**

Let's say i already got my apk downloaded in `fpath`.

With the following snippet i'm trying to remount `/system/` folder with `read/write` permission and then move my updated apk on that folder.

```
try {
    String line;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

    // open input/output facilities
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()) );

    // output the command
    osw.write("mount -o rw,remount /system");
    osw.flush();

    // read the response
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.i("UPDATE", "output mount rw " + line);
    }

    // output the command
    osw.write("cp " + fpath + " /system/app/myapp.apk");
    osw.flush();

    // read the response
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.i("UPDATE", "output cp " + line);
    }

    // output the command
    osw.write("mount -o ro,remount system");
    osw.flush();

    // read the response
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.i("UPDATE", "output mount ro " + line);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("UPDATE", "error in executing shell commands: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

This snippet gets stuck at the first readLine, just after the mount command.

**Questions:**

1. Why does it stuck there? Shouldn't i expect something to read from the input stream?
2. It just doesn't work even if i remove the readLines. Filesystem is not remount'd and file is obviously not copied. Why?
3. There's a way to avoid the `superuser` prompt asking for permissions? My app got to run on a screenless system. I cannot get a confirm by an user.
4. There's a better way to do what i need?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> There's a better way to do what i need?

<s>Copying the APK will not install it. Use [`pm`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#pm) instead of `cp`.</s>

> There's a way to avoid the superuser prompt asking for permissions?

This is up to the `su` app, so if you need one that automatically grants permissions without asking or remembers the permissions.

Comment: Copying apk into `/system/app` works! That's how you gotta install system apps

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see it was /system/app